# AWS Stepfunctions workflow using fargate as worker- how do I get to send the ouput to the next step?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-fargate

I need to make an api for stepfunctions but the problem is, how do I get the output of the first as input for the next?

Here is what I have so far:

```
{
  "Comment": "Match",
  "StartAt": "Search",
  "States": {
    "Search": {
     "Type": "Task",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
     "Parameters": {
                "Cluster": "Search-cluster",
                "TaskDefinition": "Search-task",
                "Overrides": {
                    "ContainerOverrides": [
                        {
                            "Name": "search",
                            "Command.$": "$.commands" 
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
        "Next": "Save"
    },
     "Save": {
     "Type": "Task",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
     "Parameters": {
                "Cluster": "save-cluster",
                "TaskDefinition": "save-task",
                "Overrides": {
                    "ContainerOverrides": [
                        {
                            "Name": "save",
                            "Command.$": "$.commands" 
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
        "Next": "Send"
    },
     "Send": {
     "Type": "Task",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
     "Parameters": {
                "Cluster": "send-cluster",
                "TaskDefinition": "send-task",
                "Overrides": {
                    "ContainerOverrides": [
                        {
                            "Name": "send",
                            "Command.$": "$.commands" 
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },

      "End": true
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and contacted AWS Support. Was told that it is not possible to directly return the result of a Fargate Task like you can do with Lambdas. One of the options is to store the result of your task in a separate DB like DynamoDB and write a Lambda to retrieve the value and update your input JSON with the output from the previous task.

Sidenote: In your ASL, you should look at using `ResultPath`. The default behaviour is to replace the input node with the output (result). Meaning, if in your input JSON you have values that you would like to use in subsequent states and if you don't specify `ResultPath`, they'd be lost after the first state. Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html#input-output-resultpath-amend

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to manually mange this. Lambda function's `event` parameter contains the previous function(s) return output(s).